# Как данные с одной страницы переместить на другую? PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, phpmyadmin, localhost

Ребят, я попробовал решить одну задачу, которую я придумал, оно с базой данных.
У меня есть 3 страницы: "Авторизация", "Регистрация", "Главная страница". В главную страницу можно зайти только после авторизации на странице авторизации. Так вот, я вошел через Авторизацию на главную страницу. В странице авторизации я говорил под кем мне зайти(у меня уже была регистрация). Но мне нужно когда я захожу на главную страницу под кем я уже зашёл чтобы подклются на главной страницы, к базе данных. Допустим у меня два аккаунта: админовский и обычный. Я авторизуюсь допустим под обычный. Как мне главной странице сказать что я зашёл под обычным аккаунтом чтобы использовать именно обычный аккаунт в базе данных? Простите если вы меня не поняли.

Код страницы авторизации:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="form-center-block" align="left" style="padding-left: 700px">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <label for="">Введите логин: &nbsp</label>
                <input id="login" type="text" placeholder="Введите логин" name="login">
                <br/><br/>
                <label for="password">Введите пароль: &nbsp</label>
                <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль" name="password">
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Войти">
            </form>
            <?php 
                if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
                    $userLogin = $_POST['login'];
                    $userPassword = $_POST['password'];
            
                    $mysqli = new mysqli("www.ajax.test.local", "root", "root", "accounts");
            
                    $userQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `account_data` WHERE `login` LIKE '$userLogin' AND `password` LIKE '$userPassword'");

                    if ($userQuery->num_rows > 0) {
                        echo "<script>document.location.href = '/game/index.php'</script>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Шлёте себе, например, [`Cookie`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php) с уникальным идентификатором учётной записи (если один логин может использовать только один пользователь, то отправьте логин). А на другой странице шлёте его обратно, с ним отправляете запрос в базу данных (вдруг логин кривой - пользователя нет, переадресуйте его на авторизацию). Можно использовать [`$_SESSION`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php) для упрощения.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов а это ничего что я тоже смогу послать себе куку с уникальным идентификатором автора вопроса?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов я не понимаю, но куки у меня проподает. Там где в коде он ищет пользователя, я перед "echo" добавил setcookie("user", "$userLogin"). А когда я перемещаюсь на главную страницу - куки проподает

Comment: [Как и любой другой заголовок, cookie должны передаваться до того как будут выведены какие-либо другие данные скрипта (это ограничение протокола).](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php) А у вас сначала большая часть разметки выводится.

Comment: @Ипатьев, я честно не понял проблему, поднятую Вами в Вашем вопросе. Но я догадываюсь, что это связано с безопасностью, которую в данном вопросе не рассматривают.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов поэтому надо сначала понять, что любая парольная защита, а уж тем более разделение ролей, всегда связана с безопасностью. N'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Никаких "админских" аккаунтов для подключения быть не должно, это полная ересь.
   Аккаунт для подключения к БД должен быть один.
2. Для того чтобы "переместить данные" что, как я понимаю, в данном случае означает просто узнать, авторизован ли пользователь, и какой у него статус, необходимо использовать СЕССИИ.
3. Поскольку в коде цветет и пахнет SQL инъекция, все эти защиты смысла не имеют всё равно кто угодно сможет зайти куда угодно вообще без пароля.

Comment: У меня нет админских аккаунтов, я это привёл для примера потому что было тяжело объяснить. 2. У меня не получается насчёт сессий. 3. Раз вы так считаете, то спорить с вами не могу. Я новичок в базах данных, то защита данных это для меня хардкор

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас данные о пользователях хранятся в базе данных, то Вы можете создать ещё 2 страницы с ролями и связующую страницу для ролей и юзеров (если например хотите иметь много ролей

```
username: admin;
role: { admin, moderator, user }

username: user;
role: { user }

username: moderator;
role: { moderator, user }
```

Не уверен что правильно понял вопрос.
Но чтоб перенести сам факт авторизации в системе на другие страницы обычно используют cookies или session

[edit]

```
       <?php 
            if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
                $userLogin = $_POST['login'];
                $userPassword = $_POST['password'];
        
                $mysqli = new mysqli("www.ajax.test.local", "root", "root", "accounts");
        
                $userQuery = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `account_data` WHERE `login` LIKE '$userLogin' AND `password` LIKE '$userPassword'");

                if ($userQuery->num_rows > 0) {
                    // Записать в сессию какие-то данные, и делать проверку на другой странице что там что-то записано.
                    $_SESSION['auth-user'] = $userQuery;
                    echo "<script>document.location.href = '/game/index.php'</script>";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Можете ли вы править свой вопрос. ниже своего вопроса напишите пожалуйста мой код, но переделайте как вы сделали. Без ролей, просто куки

Comment: Подсказка: перед тем как писать или читать сессию, её надо *стартовать*

Comment: Совсем забыл об этом. Подсказка в тему. Спасибо Вам!

Comment: я на главной странице написал код:

`$userDataLogin = (isset($_SESSION["auth-user"]) ? $_SESSION["auth-user"] : 0);`

`echo "$userDataLogin";`

Он мне выводит ноль

Comment: Я также стартовал сессию, но пишет какую то ошибку.

Comment: не забудьте стартовать сессию на главной странице тоже. Везде где будете использовать сессии - нужно стартовать, не помню какая там функция их запускает, но что-то похожее на ```session_start();```

Comment: Да, я написал и там и там `session_start();` попрежнему пишет, то ошибку, то ноль `$userDataLogin = (isset($_SESSION["auth-user"]) ? $_SESSION["auth-user"] : 0); echo "$userDataLogin";`

Comment: Посмотрите что записывается в переменную на странице авторизации. Возможно Вам имеет смысл подготовить вручную данные для сохранения. Либо используйте ОРМ (например RedBeanPHP) - это должно избавить Вас от SQL инъекций.
И данная библиотека возвращает удобный для работы формат данных с базы

Comment: я всего лишь хотел поучить чисто php и sql.  Мне до защиты ещё далеко. у меня не получаются сессии

Comment: @Mr_CatYT без сессии ничего не получится. скрипт на главной странице ничего не знает про то что происходило в скрипте регистрации. И чтобы передать информацию из одного в другой, и нужна сессия. А то что не получается - это нормально, это у всех так. Надо просто стараться, и всё со временем получится.

Comment: @Ипатьев это достаточно простая задачка, странно что не получается. Хотелось бы знать почему :)

Comment: Да "почему" - это-то как раз очевидно. Потому что когда РНР говорит открытым текстом **в чем заключается проблема**, то для вас, новичков, это "какая-то ошибка". то есть нет навыка работы с ошибками. что ошибку надо прочесть и понять. Если не получается - загуглить. И всё. при том, что ошибка очевидная, про неё ещё Вася в комментаз под вопросом написал

Comment: @Ипатьев я прочёл ошибку, и эта ошибка - **Фатальная** ошибка

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in W:\domains\www.ajax.test.local\game\index.php on line 3

Comment: Вот мои файлы: https://dropmefiles.com/H8CCP

Comment: @Mr_CatYT ```$result = (isset($_SESSION["auth-user"]) ? $_SESSION['auth-user'] : 0);``` попробуйте вот такой код в своём index.php

Comment: @Graf_Men и что изменилось? название переменной?

Comment: @Mr_CatYT немного неправильно у Вас скобки были расставлены...
```$result = (isset($_SESSION["auth-user"] ? $_SESSION['auth-user'] : 0));```
Вот так было у Вас.